# How to compute these probabilities?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

1. A pair of dice is cast until either the sum of seven or eight appears. How to compute the probability of a seven before an eight?
2. Now, if this pair of dice is cast until a seven appears twice or until each of a six and eight have appeared at least once. How to compute the probability of the six and eight occurring before two sevens?

Comment: Just to understand the problem: in 1., we stop once we get a 7 or an 8, right? Then, what does it mean "the probability of a seven *before* a eight"?

Answer (score 3):

**Problem 1:** The chance for a seven is $6/36 = 1/6$ and the chance for an eight is $5/36$. The chance for neither is $25/36$.

We want to compute the chance of getting neither $k$ times and then getting a seven, where $k$ goes from $0$ up. The chance is thus:

$$\frac{1}{6} + \frac{25}{36}·\frac{1}{6} + \frac{25^2}{36^2}·\frac{1}{6} + \ldots = \\ \frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^k = \frac{1}{6}·\frac{1}{1-\frac{25}{36}} = \frac{6}{11}$$

**Problem 2**

This is a bit more tricky. We are going to compute the chance for the alternative: to het two sevens but not both a six and an eight. Then, if $p$ is the chance for that to happen, what we want is $1-p$.

We have two cases:

We have a sequence of $k$ numbers, none of wich are seven or six (but can be eight), then a seven, then another sequence of $k'$ numbers that are not six nor seven, and then another seven.

OR

We have a sequence of $k$ numbers, none of wich are seven or eight (but can be six), then a seven, then another sequence of $k'$ numbers that are not eight nor seven, and then another seven.

(note that both cases are mutually exclusive)

The chance for a six is $5/36$ and the chance for nor six nor seven is $25/36$.

So we basically have to add all the numbers of the form:

$$\underbrace{\frac{25}{36}·\frac{25}{36}\ldots \frac{25}{36}}_{k \text{times}}·\frac{1}{6}·\underbrace{\frac{25}{36}·\frac{25}{36}\ldots \frac{25}{36}}_{k' \text{times}}·\frac{1}{6}$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{k'=0}^\infty \left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^k\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^{k'}\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^k·\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k'=0}^\infty \left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^{k'} = \left(\frac{6}{11}\right)^2 = \frac{36}{121}$$

That's the chance for one of the cases, but since both cases have the same chance, the total chance of the alternative is $\displaystyle\frac{72}{121}$, therefore, the chance we want is $1-\displaystyle\frac{72}{121} = \frac{49}{121}$

Comment: I don't think your answer to the second problem is right.

Answer (score 2):

For problem $1$ suppose the game ends on the $n^{th}$ throw. There are six chances of getting a $7$ on the $n^{th}$ throw to five of getting an $8$, so the probability of ending on a $7$ is $\cfrac 6{11}$.

Since this is independent of $n$ it is also the probability for all throws taken together.

Answer (score 1):

> A pair of dice is cast until either the sum of seven or eight appears. How to compute the probability of a seven before an eight?

On any roll the probability of the dice adding to 7 is $p_7 = 6/36$ and the probability of adding to 8 is $p_8 = 5/36$.  In the event that neither happens we repeat until one or the other happens.  So the probability that we end by rolling a 7 is: $$p_7/(p_7+p_8) = 6/11$$

This result can be drawn from a Markov chain: $$\left(\begin{array}{r|rrr} ~ & \text{other} & 7 & 8
\\ \hline \text{other} & 25/36 & 6/36 & 5/36
\\ 7 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} & 0
\\ 8 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1}
\end{array}\right)
$$

> Now, if this pair of dice is cast until a seven appears twice or until each of a six and eight have appeared at least once. How to compute the probability of the six and eight occurring before two sevens?

Again: $p_7 = 6/36, p_6 = 5/36, p_8 = 5/36$

Again we construct a Markov chain, and trace the trees from having rolled none of 6,7,8, to having rolled the desired numbers in the desired orders:
$$\left(\begin{array}{r|rrrrrr}
~ & () & 6\vee 8 & 7 & (6\vee 8)\wedge 7 & 6\wedge 8 & 7^2 
\\ \hline
() & 20/36 & 10/36 & 6/36 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\ 6\vee 8 & 0 & 25/36 & 0 & 6/36 & 5/36 & 0
\\ 7 & 0 & 0 & 20/36 & 10/36 & 0 & 6/36
\\ (6\vee 8)\wedge 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 25/36 & 5/36 & 6/36
\\ (6\wedge 8) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & 0
\\ 7^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1}
\end{array}\right)$$

So the probability of reaching a blue result is: $$\frac{10}{10+6}\frac{6}{6+5}\frac{6}{5+6}+\frac{6}{10+6}(\frac{6}{10+6}+\frac{10}{10+6}\frac{6}{5+6})
\\ = \frac{3519}{7744}
$$

While the probability of reaching the red result is: $$\frac{10}{10+6}(\frac{6}{6+5}\frac{5}{5+6}+\frac{5}{6+5}) +\frac{6}{10+6}\frac{10}{10+6}\frac{5}{5+6}
\\ = \frac{4225}{7744}
$$